# Print Copyright info text directly into OpenLayers canvas

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I need to add some copyright info text to my openlayers map. The site offers a button to export the map to PNG in a similar way like shown in http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-map.html So, the Copyright text must be on on the exported PNG map, too.

Hence, I cannot use a html overlay for the Copyright text but must print the text directly into the canvas, because the "Exported the map to PNG" stuff works with exporting only what's in the canvas (no html controls, or html overlays).

I tried two approaches. Both don't work ;)

1. Using **ol.source.ImageCanvas** as shown in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nachtigall/uaxevrcy/3/). The problem is that when Zooming in or out, then the text is *jumping*. But the text should just be static.
2. By getting the OpenLayers canvas after OpenLayers has initialised and then **using** this canvas **directly**.

Here's the code for the 2nd approach that is run *after* OpenLayers has done its initilisation:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.fillText('© My Copyright Text'), 500, 600);
```

This prints just nothing at all and I have no clue why. Is there anything special when "writing" to the openlayers canvas?

So what would be the best approach for adding some simple text to the map canvas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the map's `postrender` event, get the map canvas, and modify it with whatever you have in mind. In the [`export-map.html` example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-map.html), a `postrender` listener is already registered, so you can easily modify it to add attribution text, e.g.

```
map.once('postcompose', function(event) {
  var canvas = event.context.canvas;
  // Add attribution text
  event.context.textAlign = 'right';
  event.context.fillText('© My Copyright Text', canvas.width - 5, canvas.height - 5);
  // Now export the map
  canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
    saveAs(blob, 'map.png');
  });
});
```

I have created a working JSFiddle with this code: https://jsfiddle.net/ahocevar/8c4knpu6/

Comment: thanks for the answer. I see a slight conflict -- you first wrote to use `postrender`, but then in your code you use `postcompose`. Which event is the one to use? To me, looking at the OL source, it seems that `postcompose` is more closely related to the canvas rendering.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an `ol.Overlay` for this:

https://jsfiddle.net/x66v59wt/2/

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      title: 'basemap',
      source: new ol.source.Stamen({ layer: 'toner' })
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-97, 38]),
    zoom: 4
  }),
  overlays: [
    new ol.Overlay({
      id: 'copyright',
      element: document.getElementById('copyright'),
      position: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-97, 38])
    })
  ]
});

// If you want to text to be "pinned" to the map center, for example
map.getView().on('change:center', function (e) {
  map.getOverlayById('copyright').setPosition(this.getCenter());
});
```

...

```
<div id="map"></div>
<div style="display: none;">
  <div id="copyright">  
    © My Copyright text
    <br>
    Should be statically positioned even when zooming
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As in the other answer: Nope. This adds the text as html which hence cannot be exported to PNG. http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-map.html has an attribution and when you click "Download PNG" you'll see that the PNG is the very same as it is in the Canvas - all html overlays are removed from the PNG. I need the Copyright info also on the exported PNG.